# plot3D from rgl package doesn't appear

Tags: r, plot, rgl

I'm trying to use the rgl package to produce 3D plots of my graphs in RStudio. I use a Mac and I have XQuartz installed, but when I follow step-by-step tutorials for 3D plotting even the simplest plots won't work.

No warning message appears and no plot appears after I launch the command. When I bring all windows forward I can see a small one with no close/expand button and no images on it (same goes for the plot area of the workspace, nothing happens at all).

Does anybody have an idea of why this could be the case? I updated R a couple of weeks ago and all of my packages have been uninstalled and re-installed.

Thanks!

Here's the basic code I used, just in case.

```
x=runif(1000)
y=runif(1000)
z=rnorm(1000)
install.packages("rgl")
library("rgl")
plot3d(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?